# Monodroid: Access setLayerType of View-Class

Tags: android, view, mono, xamarin.android

I want to call the Method setLayerType of the View Class in a Mono for Android application. Unfortunatley I cannot access (or even see) the method. According to [Mono Documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.View.SetLayerType%28Android.Views.LayerType,Android.Graphics.Paint%29) everything should be there.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks,

faiko

Comment: Are you targeting API level 11 or above?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  You can fix this under your project settings choose "Minimum Framework Version to Target" of Android 3.1 or higher.  This has nothing to do with your minimum/target API level in your manifest.

After changing that, you will have to restart Visual Studio (or reload the project in question) and you'll notice it now references the v3.1 assembly of Mono which has some new APIs exposed.

You'll still want to wrap the call to this API around a version check like:

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb) if your minApiLevel is less than 11.